# Why when downloading files using webclient downloadfileasync I'm getting exception on the progressBar value that it's negative value?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DownloadFilesFromSite
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Queue<string> _downloadUrls = new Queue<string>();
        private List<string> urls = new List<string>();
        private List<string> sources = new List<string>();
        private List<string> links = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Sources();
        }

        private void Sources()
        {
            string link = "https://www.documentingreality.com/forum/f10/several-different-dead-chinese-women-176102/";

            for (int i = 2; i < 141; i++)
            {
                sources.Add(link + "index" + i + ".html");
            }
        }

        private void ReadSourcePage(string fn)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fn).ToList();

            string contains = "https://www.documentingreality.com/forum/attachments/f10/";

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                if (lines[i].Contains(contains))
                {
                    int index = lines[i].IndexOf("f10/") + 4;
                    int index1 = lines[i].IndexOf(".jpg") - index;
                    string result = lines[i].Substring(index, index1);

                    links.Add(contains + result + ".jpg");
                }
            }
        }

        private void downloadFiles(IEnumerable<string> urls)
        {
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
            }

            // Starts the download
            button1.Text = "Downloading...";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            label1.Visible = true;

            DownloadFile();
        }

        private void DownloadFile()
        {
            if (_downloadUrls.Any())
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;

                var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();
                string FileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                            (url.Length - url.LastIndexOf("/") - 1));

                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"E:\dr\htmlsources\" + FileName);
                label1.Text = url;
                return;
            }

            // End of the download
            button1.Text = "Download Complete";
        }

        private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // handle error scenario
                throw e.Error;
            }
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // handle cancelled scenario
            }
            DownloadFile();
        }

        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
            progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            downloadFiles(sources);
        }
    }
}
```

In the DownloadFile on the line :

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"E:\dr\htmlsources\" + FileName);
```

If I copy the url address to the chrome it will show me the source of the page and I can save and download the source page it will be about 700KB

But when clicking the button1 when it start downloading this sources it will throw exception :

ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value of '-154300' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
Parameter name: Value

And if I will not use the progressBar1 at all for testing all the downloaded sources files will be about 25KB instead about 700KB.

I tried to add the line :

```
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
```

But not seems to fix the exception.

Comment: This is not how you use async/await.   At a minimum, you should put .GetAwaiter().GetResult() on the end of DownloadFileAsync, but really, that's the worst way to to it.  If you are using async functions, then you need to use async all the way from the top.

Answer (score 0):

`DownloadFileAsync` will return immediately and then 'client' will also go out of scope.  Read up on how to use async/await functions.